# Counting the filled in numbers

Tags: c#

I would like to ask someone, how to make my program work. My idea is to make a program that takes the written `ints` in console and makes a sum only of `ints[] = {1, 3, 5, 7}`

Thank you for helping.
Adam

```
My code:

int read = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
int[] pole = {1, 3, 5, 7};
foreach (int i in pole) 
{
    
    if (read == i)
    {
        
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    else;

}
```

Comment: Fyi, `i` is already an `int`, no need to call `Convert`, what i think you want is `pole[i]` which will get you the integer value at the index (i)

Comment: Sorry, don't follow you. Suppose I've written `-1, 11, 5, 0` on the console. What is the desired output then?

Comment: @Adam Do you want to keep a running sum of any number entered by the user if/only if the number is contained within the `pole` array, ie. 1,3,5,7? You also, don't need the `else;` since you aren't actually executing any code within.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko The output should be 5 cause youve written only the number 5 of the numbers  {1, 3, 5, 7}

Comment: Is it really only those 4 or did you mean "any positive odd number"?

Comment: @RyanWilson I want to make a sum only of numbers 1,3,5,7

Comment: @Fildor yeaah, only for those 4

Comment: Ok. Then maybe let's start with the input. It seems from your code, you are expecting one single number, not multiple. So, there is not really anything to sum up... and you could just do `if (pole.Contains(read)) { ...`

Comment: @Adam Here's a fiddle that does what I think you want: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JGN97c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `Contains`? You can put it like this:

```
int[] pole = { 1, 3, 5, 7};

int sum = 0;

// We ask user again and again until (s)he presses Enter 
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Write a number or press Enter to break");

  string input = Console.ReadLine();

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    break;

  if (!int.TryParse(input, out int value))
    Console.WriteLine("Not a number"); // not a valid int
  else if (pole.Contains(value))
    sum += value;                     // int and in pole
}

// Finally, we print the sum
Console.WriteLine($"Sum is {sum}");
```

You can let user to write all the numbers in *one go*, e.g. `1,3,47,-5,100` and then match numbers and compute the `sum`, but it may be a bit too complex:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = Console.ReadLine();

int sum = Regex
  .Matches(text, "-?[0-9]+") // match the number
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .Where(item => item.Length == 1 && "1357".Contains(item)) // digits 1,3,5,7
  .Sum(item => item[0] - '0');

Console.WriteLine($"Sum is {sum}");
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/32bhsm)